# Datasets for benchmarking Fuzzy Clustering method with millions of data

Tags: dataset, benchmarking, fuzzy

We want to test the performance of some fuzzy clustering algorithms that some collaborators have developed. Our interest lies in 2D datasets with a lot of data, where we could benchmark these algorithms. Do you know where can one find such datasets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One excellent dataset is the one provided by this website.  StackExchange provides an anonymized dump of all publicly available data found on their sites here: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

You can read about the data schema here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede

I have a copy of the data from a year ago and it has over 16 million records just for this site (StackOverflow.com) and the dump has *all* of their sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dataset from http://www.mockaroo.com/. It is pretty good an you can have many option.

Answer (score 0):

There are many large "open data" collections with scientific data around the web. Some have rather, shall we say, nontrivial data set sizes of well over a Terabyte. So, depending on which size you need, take a look at genome sites like [Proteomecommons](https://proteomecommons.org/dataset.jsp?i=72639) or the [datasets from Stanford's Natural Language Processing](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/crosswikis-data.tar.bz2/) group.

Smaller dumps can be found in the geologists' projects like [this one](http://software.seg.org).